# Check, using jQuery, if an element is 'display:none' or block on click

Tags: jquery, css

I want to check and sort elements that are hidden. Is it possible to find all elements with attribute `display` and value `none`?

Comment: If you should use `.find()` then: `if($(this).find('.wrap').is(':visible')) { … }`

Answer (score 679, accepted):

You can use [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) for visible elements and [:hidden](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) to find out hidden elements. This hidden elements have `display` attribute set to `none`.

```
hiddenElements = $(':hidden');
visibleElements = $(':visible');
```

To check particular element.

```
if($('#yourID:visible').length == 0)
{

}
```

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document.
>   Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero,
>   [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

You can also use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) with `:visible`

```
if(!$('#yourID').is(':visible'))
{

}
```

If you want to check value of display then you can use [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
if($('#yourID').css('display') == 'none')
{

}
```

If you are using display the following values `display` can have.

> display: none
>
> display: inline
>
> display: block
>
> display: list-item
>
> display: inline-block

Check complete list of possible `display` values [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/display).

To check the display property with JavaScript

```
var isVisible = document.getElementById("yourID").style.display == "block";
var isHidden = document.getElementById("yourID").style.display == "none";
```

Comment: well, in my scenario, each element has an ID, so the trick works for me :)

Comment: @NicholasFrancis, I have updated my answer to find out all elements which are hidden.

Comment: Does it check inline css also. I have css `display: block;` written inline coming from jquery. i am unable to check it with your method. help me.

Comment: Is jQuery added and you are accessing the element after being added to DOM? Can you show me the code? It would be better to make a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: What is the JavaScript equiv?

Comment: var isVisible = document.getElementById("yourID").style.display == "block";
var isHidden = document.getElementById("yourID").style.display == "none";

Comment: @DhavalPanchal 5 years ago, when i was a newbie :p

Comment: We can't expect better answer from this one. Very well explained.

Comment: if( $('.serach_outer:visible').length == 0 )
 worked for me with a class name, which I think it's impossible in vanilla JS, at least haven't worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 71):

```
$("element").filter(function() { return $(this).css("display") == "none" });
```

Comment: +1: This is actually more useful than the accepted answer *for the question asked*, as this will work even if a parent element has `style="display: none;"`. Answers using `:visible` and `:hidden` will fail if you want specific element visibility and a parent element is hidden as those selectors return overall visibility on the page (which was not the question asked).

Comment: This works when running unite test in JS DOM environment.

Comment: For a tabbing plugin, it was setting `visibility: 'hidden';` in css, so the check ended up also checking: `$(this).css('visibility') != 'hidden'`

Comment: In my case this is more useful, since I have 2 error messages and one of those have `display = none` and the other `display = block`, but the page have other tabs, that causes these both messages be not visible, when I am in the other tabs,... but 1 message is visible and this selector will help me with that.

Answer (score 32):

Yes, you can use the cssfunction. The below will search all divs, but you can modify it for whatever elements you need

```
$('div').each(function(){

    if ( $(this).css('display') == 'none')
    {
       //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 23):

There are two methods in jQuery to check for visibility:

```js
$("#selector").is(":visible")
```

and

```js
$("#selector").is(":hidden")
```

You can also execute commands based on visibility in the selector;

```js
$("#selector:visible").hide()
```

or

```js
$("#selector:hidden").show()
```

Comment: Note: this will *not* return the specific visible attribute of the selected elements, as the question asks, as `:visible` also depends on parent ancestor visibility. If an ancestor is `display: none` all descendants will not be visible regardless of `display` state.

Answer (score 13):

Use this condition:

```
if (jQuery(".profile-page-cont").css('display') == 'block'){
    // Condition 
}
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$('#selector').is(':visible');
```

Comment: Note: this will *not* return the specific visible attribute of the selected elements, as the question asks, as `:visible` also depends on parent ancestor visibility. If an ancestor is `display: none` all descendants will not be visible regardless of `display` state.

Answer (score 1):

Just another shortcut i personally prefer more than .is() or .length:

```
if($('.myclass:visible')[0]){
   // is visible
}
```

which will just return `undefined` if no dom-element found for selector `.myclass:visible`

Answer (score 1):

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dexterity/hL5unjo2/1/)

```
<div id="div" style="display: none"></div>
<button class="try">Try now</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click','.try',function() {
var style = $('#div');
if (style.css("display") == "none") {
  alert("display not available");
}
});
</script>
```