# Show hide bubble div jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one question about my script. 
I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/yyNdxZ)** from *codepen.io*

I'm trying to make a bubble pop-up clicked on the link. My onclick function is working now.

My question is, if you click my **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/yyNdxZ)** page then you see there are two image and when you hover over that image then you see black color div. 
So if you click this `div` then you see `.bubble` will open but if you mouse live on this div bubble will still stay open. Ok it should be stay opening but the black div automatically getting `display:none` => I don't want it (*How can i do this.*)

Also if you click right side black color div then you see left `.bubble` still stay open so i want when i click other black `div` then i want other bubble will automatically `hide`.

Anyone can help me in this regard ?

This is my jquery function :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
            var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');       
            var toggle_switch = $(this);
            $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
              if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
                toggle_switch.html('x');
              }else{
                toggle_switch.html('x');
              }
            });
          });
        });
```

Comment: You can use  if ($('#yourID:visible').length == 1){} condition so that you don't toggle black color div. follow this answer for more detail : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15924774/3190165, if you want I can create an example for you.

Comment: @GauravKalyan please can you create an example for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just modify this piece of css :

```
.imgar:hover .delete, .imgar.selected .delete{
display: block;
}
```

Notice, I added the class `selected` so when you do the js event click add the class event to `imgar` like so :

`$('.imgar').addClass('selected');`

And don't forget to remove the class when he click back to the element :

`$('.imgar').removeClass('selected');`

**EDIT**

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('.nav-toggle').click(function(){
            var collapse_content_selector = $(this).attr('href');       
            var toggle_switch = $(this);
            $('.imgar').removeClass('selected'); // Remove the X before openning a second
            if($(collapse_content_selector).css('display')=='none'){
              $('.bubble').hide();
            }
            $(collapse_content_selector).toggle(function(){
              if($(this).css('display')=='none'){
          toggle_switch.parent().parent().removeClass('selected');
                toggle_switch.html('x');
              }else{
          toggle_switch.parent().parent().addClass('selected');
                toggle_switch.html('x');
              }
            });
          });

        });
```

**CSS**

```
.imgar:hover .delete, .imgar.selected .delete{
    display: block;
}
```

**Codepen**
http://codepen.io/SebastienBeaulieu/pen/RNPzzL

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you give me a little example ? from [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfidle.net) or [codepen](http://www.codepen.io)

Comment: See the Edit, I only put the changed css, and you have all the js code needed.

Comment: i understood that but the selected `.bubble` not remove when i click other `.imgar`

Comment: Also I updated the code in the post so ppl can see the bubble solution direct on this site you only had to add those 2 line `$('.imgar').removeClass('selected');
        $('.bubble').hide();` before the toggle to be sure to close element.

Comment: if i click second time on black color then what can i do for hide bubble ?

Comment: Oh my bad lol I forgot a condition I have editted the CodePen I will eddit this to.

Comment: Np, I'm glad I could helped you.