# jQuery attribute selector not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

In my JavaScript I use the css selector [style="display:none"] and the code works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari (on Windows) as expected.

However in Internet Explorer (version 11) it works unfortunately wrong.

For testing:
Just click on the buttons (e.g. #visible_elements_count) in Chrome and then click on the buttons in Internet Explorer. You will experience different return values.

HTML:

```
<section>
    <ul>
        <li>visible Element</li>
        <li style="display:none">invisible Element</li>
        <li>visible Element</li>
    </ul>
</section>

<button id="all_elements_count">all elements</button>
<button id="visible_elements_count">visible elements</button>
<button id="invisible_elements_count">invisible elements</button>

<!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#all_elements_count").click(function () {
        var counter = $("section ul li").length;
        alert(counter);
    });

    $("#visible_elements_count").click(function () {
        var counter = $("section ul li:not([style='display:none'])").length;
        alert(counter);
    });

    $("#invisible_elements_count").click(function () {
        var counter = $("section ul li[style='display:none']").length;
        alert(counter);
    });
</script>
```

Sources:
I read everything [about selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)! and still can not solve this problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: take a look at [Article StackoverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924751/check-if-a-element-is-displaynone-or-block-on-click-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `:hidden, :visible` with use of `.filter()`:

```
    $("#all_elements_count").click(function () {
        var counter = $("section ul li").length;
        alert(counter);
    });

    $("#visible_elements_count").click(function () {
        var counter = $("section ul li").filter(':visible').length;
        alert(counter);
    });

    $("#invisible_elements_count").click(function () {
        var counter = $("section ul li").filter(':hidden').length;
        alert(counter);
    });
```

Comment: This worked! Could you explain why using the JQuery attribute selector [style='display:none'] led to an error?

Comment: @stylesenberg it might be possible that IE behaves differently when working with attributes. I guess that's the way it might be implemented in the IE.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery `:visible` & `:hidden` pseudo selectors:

```
var counter = $("section ul li:visible").length;

var counter = $("section ul li:hidden").length;
```

For better performance, see @Jai's answer.