# jQuery run function if CSS property present

Tags: jquery, css, display

I am trying to run a function if  is visible and not allow it to run if  is visible. My code is the following but it does not work. The function runs fine.

```
function onAnyChange(){
  if ($('#text_side_content_submit').css('display') != 'none'){
  ...do something...
  }
}
```

What I would like is to use something like:

```
.css('display') == 'visible')
```

but "display" does not have such a property. Based on the manual the default value of "display" is "inline", but that breaks the code. What should I use?

Comment: I think you're looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15924751/check-if-a-element-is-displaynone-or-block-on-click-jquery

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery has **:visible** and **:hidden** selector. Use these selectors.

```
if($('#text_side_content_submit:hidden').length == 0){
// do something
```