# Filtering a tree view made of nested <ul> <li> along with child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for not entering the code I have worked on. I am explaining my doubt clearly this time. I have a tree made of nested ul and li tags. the tree node names are obtained from database. I need to filter the tree based on the name I enter in a text box. While showing the filtered tree item, if it the filtered item is a parent node, child nodes should also be listed(eventhough they don't match the text entered in texbox.)
  I have refered this link: 
 [Filter multiple <ul> lists with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375079/filter-multiple-ul-lists-with-jquery)

This link helped me to filter out a tree node by entering its name in textbox. 
But its childnodes are not visible.Please help me. Please find my code below:

```js
function func(){
 alert("Onclick function parent node...");}

function func1(){
 alert("Onclick function child node...");}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){

    var filter = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("ul li").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
            jQuery(this).hide();
        } else {
            jQuery(this).show();
            jQuery(this).children().show();
        }
    });    
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <input type="text" />

<ul class="mainlayer" id="category1">
    <li class="layer1"><a href="#" onclick="func();">item1</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="layer2"><a href="#"  onclick="func1();">hju11</a></li>
        <li class="layer2"><a>kiu12</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="layer1"><a>item2</a></li>
    <li class="layer1"><a> item3</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That question has some code in it. Nobody likes questions without code. Show us what you've tried so far please

Comment: I don't really get your question, so can you mention a case which it fails? maybe if you input 1 or 2 into the textbox..

Comment: Also I don't see any click function on the child nodes

Comment: Hi, please check my doubt... I have explained it in more detail now with code..

Comment: @AngularDoubts Your question helped me a lot. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
function func(){
 alert("Onclick function parent node...");}

function func1(){
 alert("Onclick function child node...");}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .hide{
      display:none;
    }
    </style>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){

    var filter = jQuery(this).val();
      jQuery(".menu ul > li").removeClass("hide");
      jQuery(".menu ul > li").removeClass("show");
      
        jQuery(".menu ul > li").each(function () {
           if (jQuery(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0 && !jQuery(this).hasClass('show')) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('hide');
           } else {
            jQuery(this).addClass('show');
            jQuery(this).find(' ul > li').addClass('show');
          
           }
       });       
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <input type="text" />

  <div class="menu">
      <ul class="mainlayer" id="category1">
        <li class="layer1"><a href="#" onclick="func();">item1</a>
          <ul>
            <li class="layer2"><a href="#"  onclick="func1();">hju11</a></li>
            <li class="layer2"><a>kiu12</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="layer1"><a>item2</a></li>
        <li class="layer1"><a> item3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**UPDATE**

updated snippet, where you can change `.menu` class for whatever you need

Comment: Thank you.. it works..One doubt more.. Can I do the same by giving specific class name or unique id rather than 'ul' ' li'? jQuery("#myTree").each(function () { Instead of jQuery("ul li").each(function () {};

Answer (score 0):

You can use following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() 
{

    var filter = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("ul li.layer1").each(function() 
    {
    if (jQuery(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) 
    {
        jQuery(this).hide();
    } 
    else 
    {
        jQuery(this).show();

        jQuery(this).children().show();
        var found = false;
        jQuery(this).find("li.layer2").each(function(i,obj) 
        {

        if ($(obj).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) 
        {
            $(obj).hide();
            jQuery(obj).closest('.layer1').show();
        }
        else 
        {
            $(obj).show();
            found = true;
        }

        });
        if(found==false)
        {
        jQuery(this).find("li.layer2").show();
        }
    }


    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have got a lot of help from so many developers.. Thank you all for the support and useful answers.. Please find the one among them which I felt much easier...

Instead of checking it like this,
  **jQuery("ul li").each(function () {}**
Check it as:

  **jQuery(".mainlayer>li").each(function () {}**

So that child nodes are visible and associated functions shall work...
Once again Thank you all for the useful answers.. Happy coding!